# Why Can't We Feel A Jinni?

Tags: jinn

I understand Jinn are physical in nature. If this is true then why can't we feel them when we interfere with their lives constantly?

Comment: Some consider light to be a physical item, but we can't feel it! Not every physical item can be seen or felt!

Answer (score -3):

We can't feel them, because of the creation difference of Humans and Jinns. We are created from soil, while they are created from smokeless fire.

The word **‘Jinn’** appears 32 times in 31 verses of the Quran. However, the word Aalameen has come great many times which refers to both Human and Jinn, Yet I have only gathered the Verses that specifically has the word Jinn in them.

**How Jinn are different from Humans!** [Quran says,](http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/669/viewall/world-of-jinn/)

> “Indeed We created man from dried clay of black smooth mud.  And We created the Jinn before that from the smokeless flame of fire” (Quran 15:26-27)

And in [Sahih Muslim](http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/669/viewall/world-of-jinn/). their physical structure is described as:

> “The Angels were created from light and the Jinn from smokeless fire.” (Saheeh Muslim)

The purpose of creation of Jinn, was/is to worship Allah, and that Jinns also have *believers* and *disbelievers*, as Quran says:

> ay (O’ Muhammad): It has been revealed to me that a group of Jinn listened and said; ‘Indeed we have heard a marvelous Quran.  It guides unto righteousness so we have believed in it, and we will never make partners with our lord’.”(Quran 72:1-2)

For More information, visit here:

1. [Reference 1](http://www.islamawareness.net/Jinn/jinn.html)
2. [Reference 2](http://www.jinndemons.com/jinn-in-quran/)

Hope, it Helps.

Comment: We can feel fire, this answer doesn't address the question.

Comment: This was supposed to be the best possible explanation, according to Quran and hadees. If you think it could be improved, please do suggest an edit, or point out a better ayat or hadees.

Comment: I think it could be improved by answering the question instead of pointing to unrelated verses.

Comment: Sure,, but this the most related, that i found, If you could help me find better, i would update them.

Comment: The question is on whether or not is it possible to feel Jinn not on what they are or what is the definition of Jinn.